# passing google RecaptchaResponsed via curl php

Tags: javascript, php, curl

how can i post curl login in the site with the google recapture manually 
it doesn't work it's says localhost not support

this is the code

```
global $curl;


    $link = "https://localhost.com/my-account/";
    $s = $curl->get($link, 0);
    $woocommerceloginnonce = get_string_between($s, 'woocommerce-login-nonce" value="', '"');
    $post = array(
        '_wp_http_referer' => 'https://localhost.com/my-account/',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => $gRecaptchaResponsed,
        'login' => 'Log in',
        'password' => '!$%!@#',
        'username' => 'something@example.com',
        'woocommerce-login-nonce' => $woocommerceloginnonce
    );
    $headers = array(
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36",
        "Sec-Fetch-User: ?1",
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        'referer: https://localhost.com/my-account/'
    );
    $curl->header($headers);
    echo  $s = $curl->post($link, json_decode($post), 0, 1, 0);
```

i have a class curl do the curl jobs
so how can i pass it and go to my account and i have google recapte respond 
or how can i make it with js code

Answer (score 0):

> localhost domains are no longer supported by default. If you wish to
>   continue supporting them for development you can add them to the list
>   of supported domains for your site key. Go to the admin console to
>   update your list of supported domains. We advise to use a separate key
>   for development and production and to not allow localhost on your
>   production site key.

But you can add them into google admin console

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#localhost_support